# Attach shortcuts of documents

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shortcut

I'm developing an application using Visual Studio 2010 with a SQLite Database. I must confess I'm almost a newbie on programming but I try to learn as much as I can.

I have a tab related to a textil model, and I need to attach some related documents: PDF, DOC, Images... and afterthat be able to open them. The idea I have in mind is as when you create a new email and you can add files to be attached, but only saving a shortcut of the document, not the doc itself.

Any idea?
Sorry for my English, I'm learning it, too. And thanks for your time :)

Comment: Well, I,ve been trying to find a solution and by the moment using a Listview is the best way. I've managed to drag and drop shortcuts to docs and then open them. What's next is to be able to store data in the database and then load stored items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Listview fits all my needs. When I drag and drop an item (file, folder or shortcut) there I store its name and path in the database and extract its icon to an Imagelist to be shown in the Listview. 
When loading the items I check if the file/folder exists, if not exists I load an exclamation icon from the Imagelist. If exists I assign to it the name and path and then I extract its icon again. When opening the item I call the Windows Explorer so as to open it. And that's all!
[Here's a pic of the Listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLgms.png)